# Restricted access to Facebook stories via their API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-ads-api

I'm managing ads via Facebook ads API.
The requests are made on behalf a user, which provides *access_token*. It's info:

```
Expires: Never 
Valid: True 
Origin: Web 
Scopes: public_profile, basic_info, ads_management, user_friends
```

Sometimes requests to specific stories info via their *object_story_id*-s (obtained form *AdCreative* objects) fail for unknown reason (Unsupported get request).

May be it's important that some of pages, which host this stories, are alcohol-related. But "**age_range**" for my token is **{ "min": 21 }**. That seems more weird when requests to another stories from that pages are ok.

So how can I found, where is a problem? May be there is not age-related, but some other kind of restrictions (geographical or so). How can it be determined?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you don’t have admin access to those pages, then I think you can not find out _why_ your user might not be able to “see” a certain post. (Can you see those posts directly on facebook.com if your are logged in with that user?)

Comment: following facebook spec, for *object_story_id* "The ID of the post is returned in the following format: <Page_ID>_<Story_ID>". So when I'm accessing the story using *https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/<Story_ID>*
it's retrivied normally. And when - *https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/<Page_ID>_<Story_ID>* - not (for some pages).

So there is one more thing which i don't understand - why there are two different objects.

Answer (score 0):

It had nothing to do with alcohol or age restrictions. Just a coincidence. The deal is that there is a bug on FB side related to Photo id-s. It is described (with several suggested workarounds) here :
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/311567308967873/